# Displaying Vue Component's computed property: [Vue warn]

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-resource

I created a simple Vue 2 component:

```
Vue.component('upper', {
    props: ['value'],

    template: '#upper-template',

    computed: {
        formattedValue: function() {
            return this.value.toUpperCase();
        }
    }
});
```

Here is the template:

```
<template id="upper-template">
    <span>{{ formattedValue }}</span>
</template>
```

And when I use it:

```
<upper value="test"></upper>
```

it works fine, but I am getting the following warning:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "formattedValue" is not defined on the
>   instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive
>   data properties in the data option.  (found in root instance)

Can you tell me what is wrong with my code and how can I fix this? I read the documentation, but I could not understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I tried the same locally, and I am not getting any warning. It works alright, as expected. The error is probably from a different area in the component, can you provide more code, wherever you are using `formattedValue`?

Comment: Ok, the problem was that my template was in Vue's el.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My `<template id="upper-template">` was in `new Vue({el: '#app', ...` ) (it was placed inside `<div id="app">`), and that's why I was getting that warning.